# Homestead vagrant up error

Tags: vagrant, homestead

```
/Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:169:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in configure'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm_provisioner.rb:72:in `add_config'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/plugins/kernel_v2/config/vm.rb:324:in `provision'
    from /Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:168:in `block in configure'
    from /Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:157:in `each'
    from /Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:157:in `configure'
    from /Users/shaddeler/Developer/run/Homestead/Vagrantfile:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:113:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:107:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `new'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:746:in `vagrantfile'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:492:in `host'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:479:in `hook'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:728:in `unload'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.6/bin/vagrant:177:in `<main>'
```

I enfaced this error while vagrant up

Comment: try reinitianilizing homestead

Comment: I find my problem @ Homestead.yaml. I rewirte rewrite my source folder path. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem too. Instead of a wrong indentation, I accidentally added another dash ( - ) to my Homestead.yaml file.

For example, this is the **incorrect** one:

```
- map: testing.khc.my
- to: /home/vagrant/code/testing/public
```

The **correct** one is this:

```
- map: testing.khc.my
  to: /home/vagrant/code/testing/public
```

Hope this help everyone in the future.

Comment: This is exactly what was wrong with my file. Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error too and it's a real pain. The source of the problem is a wrong indentation in the Homestead.yaml file. Check if you're using spaces or tabs.